# 'image upload' not writing to MySql database or public folder with Laravel 4.1 (with Croppa) on Fortrabbit

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, sequelpro, fortrabbit

newbie alert!
i’ve recently moved my Laravel site to Fortrabbit but when i post new images to the site, they do not write to the database or the upload\images directory.  other changes such as posting text, adding users, changing passwords etc, successfully add to the database - all was functioning properly on the local site.

some of the things i’ve tried;
changed permissions to group write on the upload directory on the Fortrabbit server with SSH,
checked public path with `{{ dd(public_path()) }}`on local and remote sites,
declared public path in \bootstrap\start.php,
declared host in \croppa\config.php,

does anyone have any ideas…

thx in advance

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Adrenaxus - the error i got was line 146 in RouteCollection.php, the whole problem was caused because in the process of validation, an error was thrown because i had two form close statements within a blade - i also had two forms within that blade.
being a newbie and thinking one might be enough i took out the first ... {{ Form::close(); }}. it was all fixed by putting that statement back in my blade, changing public path in \bootstrap\start.php & host in \croppa\config.php back to default. all working now...

Comment: If you solved your problem, please answer your own question and accept it - other users might find it useful. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the whole problem was caused because in the process of validation, an error was thrown because i had two form close statements within a blade - i also had two forms within that blade. being a newbie and thinking one might be enough i took out the first ... {{ Form::close(); }}. it was all fixed by putting that statement back in my blade, changing public path in \bootstrap\start.php & host in \croppa\config.php back to default. all working now...